# Can we compute all digits of the Euler-Mascheroni constant?

Tags: calculus, computability, computational-mathematics

Let $\gamma$ be the Euler-Mascheroni constant from calculus. Is there an algorithm that computes the $n$-th digit of the decimal expansion of $\gamma$ given $n$ as input?

For all we know $\gamma$ could be a rational number, it could even be something like $k/10^n$ and have a terminating decimal expansion. Do we run into difficulties in this case when trying to compute the $n$-th or later digits?

**Clarification**: As another example assume we have a computable strictly increasing lower bound series $a_n$ and a computable strictly decreasing upperbound series $b_n$  both converging to an unkown real number $x$: $a_n < x < b_n$ and $b_n-a_n\rightarrow0$.

Now assume that $x$ is in fact $0.5$ but we do not know this. All we see is that no matter how (finitely) many $a_n$ and $b_n$ we compute that always $a_n < 0.5 < b_n$. How can we then ever know the first digit of the decimal expansion of $x$? Ist could be $4$ or $5$.

My questions is: Could we run into a similar problem with $\gamma$? Is there a known computable function $f(n)$ that provably computes the $n$-th digit of the decimal expansion of $\gamma$ for every $n$?

Theorertically of course there is such an algorithm in any case. But can we write it down not knowing wether $\gamma$ is irrational?

Comment: Are you seeking for Euler constant version of [*BBP algorithm*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula)?

Comment: I asked a related question yesterday...Wikipedia defines a number to be computable if there is an algorithm that approximates it to any desired precision. Now I realize it's not obvious whether this is equivalent to computing arbitrary digit (possibly with a different algorithm)...

Comment: I found this blog by Hamkins: http://jdh.hamkins.org/alan-turing-on-computable-numbers/ Look at the paragraph that starts with "But let me clear up a confusing point". He says digits computable is the same as computable to any precision. Though the two definitions have subtle difference in other respects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice , we would be screwed in the case the decimal expansion is terminating. Nevertheless, $\gamma$ is computable also in this case since if it has a terminating decimal expansion, it is rational and then there is an algorithm to determine all digits. That would not help us since we would not know whether this is actually the case.

The difficulty you describe is known as the equality problem. It is in general not possible to decide the equality of two expressions if they can be "complicated enough". Not sure whether the well known limit for $\gamma$ falls into this category.

That the decimal expansion of $\gamma$ terminates is even less likely than that $\gamma$ is rational, but as far as I know, we cannot rule it out.

Comment: Why is the decimal expansion less likely to terminate? Are there more rational numbers with repeating decimal expansions than with terminating ones in general?

Comment: Assuming , $\gamma$ is rational, we know that the denominator (written in lowest possible terms) must be huge. That it has no prime factors other than $2$ and $5$ is extremely unlikely since there are very few such numbers : Upto $10^{100}$ , there are for example just $24\ 002$ such numbers (including $1$)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you look at the series expansion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant#Series_expansions

One can approximate the constant by something which is easy to compute $- \log(n) + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$. There is also a guarantee about how fast this converges to $\gamma$ as $n$ tends to infinity. Using that guarantee you can be sure about the first digits. It is proven that the denominator would have to huge if $\gamma$ is rational.

Comment: We can compute aribtrary close approximations of course. But that's not the question. If it is indeed rational with a power of 10 denominator, how can we ever be sure about its last nonzero digit?

Comment: If $\gamma$ actually has a terminating decimal expansion, we could not know whether the correct value is the terminating decimal expansion we would assume after having found approximations close enough to it or whether $\gamma$ is smaller , but so close that we cannot distinguish it. In this case, the last digit would be wrong.

Comment: If the decimal expansion is terminating, then there is a trivial algorithm which computes it; `return n < N ? a[n] : 0` for some constant array `a` of length `N`. Actually proving that the digits the algorithm computes *are* those of the Euler-Mascheroni constant is another matter.

Comment: @kaya3 Exactly that is the point ! We would first have to prove that $\gamma$ is actually equal to this terminating decimal expansion.